# regx to check + in entire string using javascript or jquery

Tags: regex, reactjs

i am trying to validate input string to chech whether it contains '+' symbol anywhere in the string. i used for of loop but didnt get what is exprected.

```
const isMobileValidWithoutPlus = funcLib.isValidMobileWithoutPlus(mobileNumber);

isValidMobileWithoutPlus(mobileNumber) {
    if (!mobileNumber) {
      return false;
    }
    const checkRegex = new RegExp('\\+?\\d+');
    return checkRegex.test(mobileNumber);
  }

but able to get desired out.
```

Comment: You are not checking for `?`, your `/\+?\d+/` regex searches for chunks of 1+ digits optionally preceded with a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for this would be

```
const rgx = new RegExp(/\+/gm);
```

Your regular expression checks if you have a string that can either start with + or not, and is followed by one or more numbers. But you're saying you want to just check if there's a "+" anywhere in the number. For that you can use this regex above.

Also, do you need to use a regex?

You can do this using indexOf on a string if using regex is not a must.

```
let number = "+001234";
function hasPlus(number) {
    return number.indexOf('+') !== -1;
}
```

Regular expressions are generally useful when you don't have one specific string that you're looking for, or when you want to find all the apparitions of a regex in a longer string. In your case, checking if a string contains "+", it isn't necessary to use them.

Comment: i am looking for regex to check + in anywhere in string